# Does command Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs only bring back details from last 30 days?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to get last sign-in time for some accounts. The code is as following:

`Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserId eq '$userId'" -Top 1 | Select CreatedDateTime, IsInteractive, AppDisplayName`

This will bring back date if it is within 30 days but it retruns nothing if it is older than 30 days. I need to bring back date older than 30 days. I am using AzureADPreview.

Comment: yes Audit-/SignInLogs in AzureAd keep the data only for 30 days. If you need a loger history you have to collect the logs locally or use a analytics workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs
```

The above command Gives or Keeps logs only for the last 30 days.

Alternatively, if you want to get users createdDate time, last interactive sign-in you can use Microsoft Graph api to get all details.

I have got all the details required and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts#how-to-detect-inactive-user-accounts) as below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,signInActivity,createdDateTime
```

[image]

The others ways are you can log all deatils daily to a file and then check them.

**Edit:**
In **modify permissions** you can get the required permission and add(Click on consent) the permissions.

[image]

**My consented permissions are:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to run this command under my username but I get the following error message "Calling principal does not have required MSGraph permissions AuditLog.Read.All"

Comment: You need to add that permission then you will get